# regexp_substr to bring back data before a foward slash

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I have the following pattern of characters in a dataset. I need to manipulate the data & cross refer it to another table. I'm trying to write a regexp_substr to bring back data before a foward slash starting from the left. for example:-

```
abc/ab/123/zzz
```

so I need to get the following results back to then compare to another table

```
abc
abc/ab
abc/ab/123
```

I have worked out the other logic but an struggling with the various regexp.

Comment: Don't use `regexp_substr`. You can use `substr(col, 1, instr(col, '/', -1))` or `regexp_replace(col, '(/)[^/]*$', '\1')`. Then write a recursive query to get all the iterations.

Comment: I've been using the following for the 'abc' result, but now need the 'abc/ab' result.
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc/123/123', '[^\\^/]+') "changes" FROM DUAL;

Comment: As mentioned you need a recursive query in order to get from substring to substring. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the recursive query with `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`:

```
with cte(col) as
(
  select substr(col, 1, instr(col, '/', -1) - 1) from mytable
  union all
  select substr(col, 1, instr(col, '/', -1) - 1) from cte where instr(col, '/') > 0
)
select col from cte;
```

And here is the query with `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
with cte(col) as
(
  select regexp_replace(col, '/[^/]*$', '') from mytable
  union all
  select regexp_replace(col, '/[^/]*$', '') from cte where instr(col, '/') > 0
)
select col from cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression. You can do it with (faster) string functions:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e718/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, value ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'abc/ab/123/zzz' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH bounds ( id, value, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         INSTR( value, '/', 1 )
  FROM   test_data
  WHERE  INSTR( value, '/', 1 ) > 0
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         INSTR( value, '/', end_pos + 1 )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  INSTR( value, '/', end_pos + 1 ) > 0
)
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR( value, 1, end_pos ) AS item
FROM   bounds
ORDER BY id, end_pos
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e718/8/0)**:

```
| ID |        ITEM |
|----|-------------|
|  1 |        abc/ |
|  1 |     abc/ab/ |
|  1 | abc/ab/123/ |
```

However, if you did want to use regular expressions then you could do:

**Query 2**:

```
WITH bounds ( id, value, lvl, item ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         1,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?/', 1, 1 )
  FROM   test_data
  WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?/', 1, 1 ) IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         lvl + 1,
         item || REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?/', 1, lvl + 1 )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?/', 1, lvl + 1 ) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT id,
       item
FROM   bounds
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e718/8/1)**:

```
| ID |        ITEM |
|----|-------------|
|  1 |        abc/ |
|  1 |     abc/ab/ |
|  1 | abc/ab/123/ |
```

Comment: Can you get it without the / on the end?

Comment: @LeeMurray Use `SUBSTR( value, 1, end_pos - 1 )` instead.

Comment: You're missing the last element of the list, 'zzz'. Don't forget to also check where the element is followed by the end of the line.

Comment: @Gary_W I did not forget - it was not in the OP's expected output.